# Javascript- If node sibling is an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I determine if a node sibling is an image?

```
function linkify() {
if(supports3DTransforms && remove == 0) {
    var selector = '.linkroll a';
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for(var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];

        var sibling = node.nextSibling; // Dont know if this is right

        // I want to add if sibling is not an image...
        if(!node.className || !node.className.match(/roll/g)){

            node.className += ' roll';
            node.innerHTML = '<span data-title="'+ node.text +'">' + node.innerHTML + '</span>';

        }
    };
}
}
```

In other words, I am trying to run this function on all hyperlinks within a div with the class of `linkroll`, but I do not want it to apply to any hyperlinked images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nodeName` property of DOM elements.

```
if(sibling.nodeName != "IMG")
// do something
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
function linkify() {
    if (supports3DTransforms && remove == 0) {
        var selector = '.linkroll a';
        $(selector).filter(function () {
            var next = this.nextSibling;
            console.log(this, $(this).next().is('img'))
            return !$(this).next().is('img')
        }).addClass('roll').html(function () {
            return '<span data-title="' + $(this).text() + '">' + this.innerHTML + '</span>'
        })
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fP2Wz/)

Answer (score 0):

Very easy solution is using this below code if ur ready to use jquery..

```
if($("a:not(:has(img))")){
  // do some thing here 
  }
```